# iOS UILabel not supporting all UTF-8 languages

Tags: ios, utf-8, uilabel

I am using UTF-8 encoding for parsing data from JSON, it is working for quite number of languages, but some languages are displaying good in console, but when i try to display them in UILabel they end up showing question marks or garbage characters.

e.g

Amharic አማርኛ

Burmese မြန်မာစာ

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to add specialized/custom fonts for those languages - the system defined/standard font won't render those languages.

Comment: Check out something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051658/ios-localization-can-i-use-2-ttf-file-in-the-plist

Comment: Font I am using MyriadPro-Regular, thats working in android, but not in iOS

Answer (score 1):

You have to use special font that provides these characters. "Abyssinica SIL" (http://software.sil.org/abyssinica/download/) worked in my case for Amharic.
For Burmese characters you can use "Zawgyi-One" (http://www.rfa.org/burmese/help/font_download_english.html
).